# How to execute a groovy closure inside node in Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Sorry I couldn't come up with a good title that explains what I mean. So currently we have this build plugin defined in shared library:

```
//myBuildPlugin.groovy
def call(body) {

    def pipelineParams = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    node('some-label') {
       body()
    }
}
```

Now I ultimately want to be able to add my own steps like:

```
//Jenkinsfile
myBuildPlugin {
    doBuild { 
        mavenToolId = 'my_maven3'
        deployMavenArtifact = true
    }
    doUnitTests {
        publishResult = false
    }

    doDocker {
       dockerRegistry = 'http://xyz'
    }
    // other components
}
```

And so each project needs to include stages they need, like for example another project may only need this:

```
myBuildPlugin {
    doBuild { 
        mavenToolId = 'my_maven3'
        deployMavenArtifact = true
    }
}
```

and `doBuild`, for example, is another groovy class:

```
//doBuild.groovy
def call(body) {
    def pipelineParams = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()
    stage('Maven Build') {
       sh 'mvn clean verify'
    }
}
```

The problem is that Jenkins keeps asking me to approve method invocation on the line `body()` and even though I approve the script, it still asks me that which made me to think perhaps I can't call `body()` inside `node {...}`

Does anyone know if this is possible?

*P.S. I'm not expert in groovy code*

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Yeikel No, nobody replied and I tried different things but didn't work. I ended up with ugly style like this `new DoBuild(this, params).call()` I don't like it but had to get it working